# How to install awdark theme into ttk python

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I want to have the awdark ttk theme for my app, but I can't figure out how to install it. I found source files here https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl-awthemes/ but I don't know where to put any of the files. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm on windows 10, python3.8.3 64bit.

Comment: I don't think you could use this theme directly.You may need to learn about `tcl/tk` and use `tkinter.tk.call()` to call those functions.

Comment: You can have a look at the [ttkthemes](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkthemes), it is a collection of themes for ttk. Though awthemes is not part of it, it might help you figure out how to use it with python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the themes by executing a few tcl commands:

1. Tell tcl where to find awthemes

   ```
   root.tk.eval("""
       set base_theme_dir /path/to/downloaded/theme/awthemes-9.2.2/

       package ifneeded awthemes 9.2.2 \
           [list source [file join $base_theme_dir awthemes.tcl]]
       package ifneeded colorutils 4.8 \
           [list source [file join $base_theme_dir colorutils.tcl]]
       package ifneeded awdark 7.7 \
           [list source [file join $base_theme_dir awdark.tcl]]
       # ... (you can add the other themes from the package if you want
       """)
   ```
2. Load the awdark theme: `root.tk.call("package", "require", 'awdark')`
3. Change the theme the usual way: `style.theme_use('awdark')`

Here is a full example:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)

# tell tcl where to find the awthemes packages
root.tk.eval("""
set base_theme_dir /path/to/downloaded/theme/awthemes-9.2.2/

package ifneeded awthemes 9.2.2 \
    [list source [file join $base_theme_dir awthemes.tcl]]
package ifneeded colorutils 4.8 \
    [list source [file join $base_theme_dir colorutils.tcl]]
package ifneeded awdark 7.7 \
    [list source [file join $base_theme_dir awdark.tcl]]
package ifneeded awlight 7.6 \
    [list source [file join $base_theme_dir awlight.tcl]]
""")
# load the awdark and awlight themes
root.tk.call("package", "require", 'awdark')
root.tk.call("package", "require", 'awlight')

print(style.theme_names())
# --> ('awlight', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'awdark', 'classic')

style.theme_use('awdark')

ttk.Button(root, text='Button').pack()
ttk.Checkbutton(root, text='Check Button').pack()
ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='Radio Button').pack()
root.configure(bg=style.lookup('TFrame', 'background'))
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you move the source of the `tcl` package to the `pythonPath/tcl`,it could avoid using `root.tk.eval("""
set base_theme_dir /path/to/downloaded/theme/awthemes-9.....`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA yes sure, I am not that familiar with tcl/tk so I just adapted the code from the ttkthemes library to load the theme.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I expected it would be a tcl command but I don't know much about tcl/tk so I wouldn't have known where to start.